# Поиск в массиве

Tags: java, массивы

Помогите понять, что не так. Надо введенный текст сравнить с массивом `eng` и потом выдать значения массива `rus`:

```
private static void Task15() {
        System.out.println("enter");
        char[] eng = { 'q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p', 'a',
                's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'v',
                'b', 'n', 'm', 'Q', 'W', 'E', 'R', 'T', 'Y', 'U', 'I', 'O',
                'P', 'A', 'S', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'Z', 'X',
                'C', 'V', 'B', 'N', 'M' };
        char[] rus = { 'й', 'ц', 'у', 'к', 'е', 'н', 'г', 'ш', 'щ', 'з', 'ф',
                'ы', 'в', 'а', 'п', 'р', 'о', 'л', 'д', 'я', 'ч', 'с', 'м',
                'и', 'т', 'ь', 'Й', 'Ц', 'У', 'К', 'Е', 'Н', 'Г', 'Ш', 'Щ',
                'З', 'Ф', 'Ы', 'В', 'А', 'П', 'Р', 'О', 'Л', 'Д', 'Я', 'Ч',
                'С', 'М', 'И', 'Т', 'Ь' };

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        char[] string = str.toCharArray();

        char[] mas = new char[string.length];

        int i;
        int code;

        for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
            code = Arrays.binarySearch(eng, string[i]);
            if (string[i] == eng[code]) {
                mas[i] = rus[code];
                System.out.println(rus[code]);
            } else
                System.out.println("LAzha");

            System.out.println(new String(mas));
        }


    }
```

Comment: Если вы совсем не разбираетесь в теме, прочитайте длинную и скучную книгу по программированию. И выполните все упражнения. Нет, видеокурсов недостаточно. Нет, просто и весело не будет. Нет, за три часа разобраться не получится. Да, мы все прочли такие книги.

Comment: спасибо Влад! Вы не поверите, вот задачка из книги, я и застрял...

Comment: О! Если это из книги, тогда респект.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Бинарный поиск работает правильно только на отсортированных данных. Arrays.binarySearch соответственно работает у вас неверно.

Касательно решения, предлагаю два варианта:

Сделать Map:

```
HashMap<Character, Character> map = new HashMap<Character, Character>();
     char[] eng = { 'q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p', 'a',
                    's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'v',
                    'b', 'n', 'm', 'Q', 'W', 'E', 'R', 'T', 'Y', 'U', 'I', 'O',
                    'P', 'A', 'S', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'Z', 'X',
                    'C', 'V', 'B', 'N', 'M' };
   char[] rus = { 'й', 'ц', 'у', 'к', 'е', 'н', 'г', 'ш', 'щ', 'з', 'ф',
                    'ы', 'в', 'а', 'п', 'р', 'о', 'л', 'д', 'я', 'ч', 'с', 'м',
                    'и', 'т', 'ь', 'Й', 'Ц', 'У', 'К', 'Е', 'Н', 'Г', 'Ш', 'Щ',
                    'З', 'Ф', 'Ы', 'В', 'А', 'П', 'Р', 'О', 'Л', 'Д', 'Я', 'Ч',
                    'С', 'М', 'И', 'Т', 'Ь' };
   for(int i = 0; i < eng.length; i++){
        map.put(eng[i], rus[i]);
   }
```

Либо List:

```
List engList = Arrays.asList(eng);
```

и далее использовать `engList.indexOf(string[i])`